# Block a specific url in HOSTS file

Tags: blocking, hosts-file

I can block a website by editing the file `hosts` located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`<sup>Windows 8.1</sup> and adding `127.0.0.1 example.com` at the end. But  I cannot figure out that how can I block a specific site such as `example.com/foo` so that the site `example.com` can open but `example.com/foo` cannot open. I tried doing it but it didn't work.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't want to use any extension or other thing. I only want to edit `hosts`.

Comment: It cannot be done from `hosts`. Did you actually read the duplicate QA?